# Formatted Date in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

How can i extract the date stored in database? Example this date is stored in database `2012-01-02` and i want to get the month the day 
and year.

```
year = 2012
month = 01
day = 02
```

Comment: hi,my question is i want to get the year,month,day and display separately in form textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT MONTH(date_col) AS month
     , YEAR(date_col) AS YEAR
     , DAYOFMONTH(date_col) AS day
  FROM tablename 
...
```

[`Year()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)
[`month()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)
[`dayofmonth()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

Answer (score 0):

Simply read it out of the database into a date object and use the date objects methods to get the information you are wanting